# Mac OS-X Android Studio Genymotion Emulator Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion

I have try to run a project in Genymotion from Android Studio. But each time failed. It shows error -

```
11:58:03 AM Genymotion: Loading Genymotion library
11:58:03 AM Genymotion: Genymotion directory:/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS
11:58:03 AM Genymotion: Trying to initialize engine
11:58:03 AM Genymotion: Initialize Engine: failed
```

I have install Google Nexux 5 device in Genymotion and install Genymotion plugin in Android Studio.

Installed softwares are below.

- OS-X v10.10.4
- Android Studio v1.2.2
- Oracle Virtual Box v5.0.0
- Geny motion latest version

I have try many suggestion from online. But nothing work. Please get me out from here.

Answer (score 1):

This might be compatibility issue between Genymotion plugin and VirtualBox.

In Genymotion FAQ, they mentions that compatible VirtualBox version is 4.3.12.  ( See [What are the VirtualBox versions compatible with Genymotion?](https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/support?chapter=compatible-virtualbox-versions#faq) )

In my environment, Genymotion itself version 2.5.2 and it's plugin version 1.0.3, the highest VirtualBox version which can work with Genymotion plugin was 4.3.28.

So, unfortunately, even though virtual device can be executed from Genymotion.app with VirtualBox 5.0, Genymotion plugin seems can not be work with VirtualBox 4.3.30 and above...

Comment: If you agree with my answer, you can post support request to Genymotion. The URL is [Here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support#contact)

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your Genymotion and also the VirtualBox to the newest version.  I upgraded Mac OS to 11 and the Genymotion cannot be started.  After I upgraded both applications, it works again.